# Why Masked Textbox Not Working 00-00-1900?

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

I am new to WinForms.

When I am trying to implement the masked text box, I got one error.

I want a mask of `00-00-1900` where `00` handle any number, but `19` is fixed and cannot be overwritten by the user. How do I do that?

Examples of valid input are `19-12-1988` and `12-01-1958`.

Comment: I am using C#,. But You can tell VB also. I understand.

Comment: Try this in Your System. Then Only You Under stand 19 is acceped all Digit

Comment: i think he is asking how to overrul the 9 (mask as digit or space) so the textbox is filled like: "__-__-19__" so you dont have to add 19

Comment: You say got "one error" - what is the error? Is it a runtime exception? Is it just incorrect from your standpoint?

Comment: I think he can't get 19 is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**00-00-1900** in Mask Take **-**-1___ Because 0 and 9 are the Masked text which refers, numeric.

> 0 - Digit, required. This element will accept any single digit between
>   0 and 9.
>
> 9 - Digit or space, optional.

You Just Right Click The Masked Text Box, And Go to Property. Click and Change Mask to 00-00-1\900.

You will get what you want.

```
1900 to 1999 in 1900.
```

Comment: Thanks Eswaran. You only Understand myproblem.

Answer (score 2):

> `0` Digit, required. This element will accept any single digit between 0 and 9.
>
> `9` Digit or space, optional.
>
> `\` Escape. Escapes a mask character, turning it into a literal. "\" is the escape sequence for a backslash.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

Since `9` is a special character, but you want to treat it as a literal, you need to escape it with `\`.

So I guess your mask needs to be `00-00-1\900` which I'd write as `@"00-00-1\900"` in C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx), see the remarks section. Sadly, it doesn't state whether you can make the 19 aspect of the last four digits fixed - you may need to write your own checks to enforce this.

Comment: It clearly states what the escape character is in the very remarks section you linked.

Comment: I missed the last line in the table on that MSDN page and your comment, CodeInChaos. the \ is the way forward :)